# cloud foundry timeout when installing vmc

Tags: timeout, cloud-foundry

I wanted to try cloud foundry. The installation process failed at installing vmc because :

```
root $ gem install vmc
vmc target
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::RemoteFetcher::FetchError)
    Errno::ETIMEDOUT: Connection timed out - connect(2) (http://rubygems.org/gems/addressable-2.3.3.gem)
```

Any clues ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally it works after waiting a few (but MongoDB is desactivated ...).